# Why is $C(n + r − 1, r) = C(n + r − 1, n − 1)$, specifically why is $r$ equivalent to $n-1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have this theorem in my discrete math textbook:

There are $C(n + r − 1, r) = C(n + r − 1, n − 1)$ r-combinations from a set with n elements when repetition of elements is allowed.

I can't figure out how these two are equivalent when $n-1$ and $r$ seemingly have nothing to do with each other?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They have plenty to do with each other --- they add up to $n+r-1$.

Comment: When you say "15 choose 4" it is like saying "15 don't choose the other 11". The number of ways of doing it is same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of $ C(n,r) = \dfrac{n!}{r!\cdot (n-r)!}$

$$C(n+r-1,r) =  \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!\cdot (n+r-1-r)!} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!\cdot (n-1)!} \tag{1}$$

$$C(n+r-1,n-1) = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot (n+r-1-(n-1))!} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot r!} \tag{2}$$

$(1) = (2)$

Logically one can say that choosing $r$ things out of $n+r-1$ is same as choosing $n+r-1-r = n-1$ (left out part). Hence they are equal !

Hope this is clear !

Comment: yeah this helps a lot, I didn't understand what c(n,r) meant exactly. Thanks!

Comment: C(n,r) means the number of ways of selecting 'r' different things from 'n' things. This is called as COMBINATION and hence the notation C(n,r).

Answer (score 4):

It is more generally true that
$$\binom{N}{k}=\binom{N}{N-k}$$
for any $0\leq k\leq N$. This is clear because the number of ways of choosing $k$ things to save out of $N$ things is the same as the number of ways of choosing $N-k$ things to throw out.

Letting
$$\begin{align*}
N&=(n-1)+r & \quad k=r\\
&=n+r-1
\end{align*}$$ then gives the result that you're asking about.