# Why is it important to know that $C(n+r-1, r)$ is equivalent to $C(n+r-1, n-1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am still a bit fuzzy on why the two are equivalent though I know its answered here [Why is $C(n + r − 1, r) = C(n + r − 1, n − 1)$, specifically why is $r$ equivalent to $n-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322120/why-is-cn-r-%E2%88%92-1-r-cn-r-%E2%88%92-1-n-%E2%88%92-1-specifically-why-is-r-equivale)

But my question is, what types of problems/situations would you use one form over the other? Could I just memorize one?

Comment: This is the formula for a "stars and bars" problem. In the first form, we are simply picking the  stars. In the second we are picking the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can memorize one, since $\binom nr = \binom n{n-r}$, but it's really a good idea to be able to flexibly move between both forms as needed. For instance, memorizing $\binom{n+r-1}r$ alone might leave you hanging if you're looking for an intuitive, deep, and/or combinatorial interpretation of the expression after making some substitution like $n-1 = F(k)$. Being able to rearrange terms is often helpful and convenient.

Indeed, in such a situation, it may make more sense to express it as $\binom{F(k)+r}{F(k)}$ (the second version) as opposed to $\binom{F(k)+r}{r}$ (the first version), especially if you want to construct a combinatorial proof of something.